# Java: change the rectangle shape to some other on button click

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the shape of rectangle to oval when i click the button. what is the code i have to write in the actionPerformed section ? Is there any other way to do the below problem easily?

```
 
        public class Shapechange extends JFrame
        {
            public Shapechange()
            {
                setSize(300,400);
                setTitle("Shape Change");
                MyPanel pane=new MyPanel();
                add(pane);
            }
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                Shapechange s=new Shapechange();
                s.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                s.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        class MyPanel extends JPanel 
        {
            JButton button;
            public  MyShape shape=new MyShape();
            public MyPanel()
            {
                button=new JButton("Click");
                add(button);
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                    {
                      //what i do to chage shape from rect to oval
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                shape.rectangledrawing(g);
```

}
    }
    class MyShape
    {
        public void rectangledrawing(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawRect(100, 200, 250, 300 );
        }
       public void ovaldrawing(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawOval(100, 200, 250, 300);
        }
    }

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you always draw rectangle, try use some flag for switching. Example code:

```
public class Shapechange extends JFrame {
    public Shapechange() {
        setSize(300, 400);
        setTitle("Shape Change");
        MyPanel pane = new MyPanel(this);
        add(pane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shapechange s = new Shapechange();
        s.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        s.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    JButton button;
    public MyShape shape = new MyShape();
    private boolean b = true;

    public MyPanel(final Shapechange shapechange) {
        button = new JButton("Click");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                b = !b;
                shapechange.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (b) {
            shape.rectangledrawing(g);
        } else {
            shape.ovaldrawing(g);
        }

    }
}

class MyShape {
    public void rectangledrawing(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(100, 200, 250, 300);
    }

    public void ovaldrawing(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(100, 200, 250, 300);
    }

}
```

Comment: splendid. But why you write Shapechange.repaint(); (It's shows error like non static....). i just give repaint() it works..

Comment: one more help: i just want only oval after click the button. Do u know ?

Comment: shapechange - was passed to the MyPanel in constructor and haven't error!( public MyPanel(final Shapechange shapechange) ). If you watch my code carefully, you will see it. It draws only rectangle or oval

Comment: that's great. sorry for the above. can you please explain what is the difference between repaint() and colorchange.repaint() in actionPerformed ?

Comment: As I think, you draw all on your JFrame, because you override paint method of MyPanel, because of that you must repaint parent container.

Comment: Happy 3 figure rep.  :)